# Changing the size of an ePub book

Tags: epub, epub3

Does anyone know how I set the width and height for an epub book?

I've noticed that there are books with different sizes and I am trying to work out how they do this.

I've been reading [the spec](http://www.idpf.org/epub/30/spec/) but as yet I can't work it out?

Is it just done in CSS or is there part of the spec I need to use?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here: http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/Fixed_layout_ePub

For iBooks you need to a a special xml document in the META-INF folder called com.apple.ibooks.display-options.xml with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<display_options>
  <platform name="*">
     <option name="fixed-layout">true</option>
  </platform>
</display_options>
```

Then you can set `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1000, height=1000"></meta>` in each xhtml file or `body {width: 709px; height: 652px; }` in css.

For other eBook readers you are meant to be able to add:

```
    <meta name="rendition:layout">pre-paginated</meta>
    <meta name="rendition:orientation">landscape</meta>
```

in the package definition but I have not tested this. More about that can be found in the spec http://www.idpf.org/epub/fxl/

Edit: you also need to set the same in your body so they all match. If you want full screen images you also need to set the height and width to be the same on these too with absolute positioning (top: 0, left: 0 as well).

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. Viewport attribute:

You should set it on the head of each html:

```
< head >
...
< meta content="width=566, height=623" name="viewport" / > 
...
< / head >
```

This method is specially usedful for Fixed Layout eBooks.

2. Set margins on the CSS file for the main div

Regards,
AM